# Linux socket send() error EAGAIN

Tags: c, sockets, http, tcp, proxy

I am designing an HTTP tunnel using a proxy and the HTTP `CONNECT` request. About 90% of the time, when I try to send my connect request `CONNECT 192.168.1.68:3001 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` the send fails, returning `errno = 11, "Try Again"`.

I am using non-blocking sockets, and the socket is closed then re-opened between connect attempts. I don't think the send buffer is full, because I am not sending much data. I'm confused why it is sometimes connecting and sometimes not (and there doesn't appear to be a pattern, sometimes it will connect twice in a row, sometimes there are 10 failures between connects).

What are some of the reasons that I could be getting this error?

Edit:

(Code)

```
if (connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize)) {
    ...
    char message[80];
    sprintf(message, "CONNECT 192.168.1.68:3001 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
    printf("*J* Message loaded.\n"); //*J*
    printf("*J* %s\n", message); //*J*
    if (send(sock, message, strlen(message) + 1, 0) < 0) printf("*J* Send Failed: %d\n", errno); 
    else printf("*J* Data Sent.\n");
    }
...
printf("\n*J* Close Socket (RESET HOST COMMAND)");
closesocket(sock);
```

(Output)

```
[SUCCESS]
*J* Starting connect...
*J* Message loaded.
*J* CONNECT 192.168.1.68:3001 HTTP/1.1


*J* Data Sent.
*J* rv = 1
*J* Ending connect...

[FAIL]
*J* Starting connect...
*J* Message loaded.
*J* CONNECT 192.168.1.68:3001 HTTP/1.1


*J* Send Failed: 11
*J* Ending connect...
```

Comment: post your code and output

Comment: Are you reading the the response from the proxy after sending the `CONNECT` command each time?

Comment: Why is this `if (connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize))`, instead of `if (connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize) != -1)`?

Comment: @EsmaeelE Code Added (what I could, its a large corporate program, which is part of the problem of finding a fix :P)

Comment: Also, you `send()` to `sock` but close `pcsptr->hPort`, what?

Comment: @dbush Not currently reading back the response. Would that cause successive connects to fail?

Comment: @JasonBrown, perhaps because you are not closing the connections and there is a limit in the server side.

Comment: If the proxy indicated that the `CONNECT` didn't work and that it closed the connection, definitely.  With HTTP you need to read a response before sending another request.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I believe connect returns 0 on success, so they are equivalent. Good catch on the reference, but that isn't the issue; that's just from another part of the code, it points to the right socket info.

Comment: The proxy is not required to close the connection if `CONNECT` fails. The proxy might require authentication, for example, which usually involves keeping the connection open until authentication is finished (which in of itself may require multiple HTTP requests to complete). The client MUST parse a proxy's HTTP responses and act accordingly. A proxy will close its connection to the client only if an HTTP response includes a `Connection: close` header, or if the tunnel is successfully established and then the connection to the next server is closed or lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several bugs in your code:

1. `connect()` returns 0 on success and -1 on error.  An `if` statement evaluates to true for any non-zero value.  Which means your code is sending the `CONNECT` message when `connect()` is failing with an error.  However, not all errors are fatal.  In particular, since you are using a non-blocking socket, an `EINPROGRESS`/`WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error indicates the connection is still pending and you need to use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to wait for the socket to actually finish connecting (or fail).  So, your code would only work if `connect()` connects asynchronously and just happens to fully connect to the proxy before you have a chance to call `send()`.  But this is behavior you should not rely on.  You need to handle errors correctly.
2. the return value of `send()` specifies how many bytes were actually accepted, or -1 on error.  Fewer bytes than requested may be accepted (especially on a non-blocking socket).  And you need to handle non-fatal errors, in particular `(WSA)EWOULDBLOCK` (and `EAGAIN`, and possibly also `EINTR`, on non-Windows platforms), which means the socket was unable to accept new data at the moment `send()` was called, so call `send()` again.  You should be calling `send()` in a loop until all bytes have been sent, or a fatal error occurs.
3. Even if you were `send()`'ing data correctly, your use of `+ 1` after `strlen()` is also wrong.  You are including the null terminator in the data to be sent, but that is not part of the `CONNECT` protocol.  The null terminator will be treated by the proxy as application data and will be forwarded as-is through the tunnel to the next server (if the tunnel is successfully opened), breaking communications with that server.

With that said, try something more like the following instead.  Your use of `closeocket()` indicates you are programming for Windows, so this is Windows-specific:

```
int ret, err;
...
ret = connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize);
if (ret == -1)
{
    err = WSAGetLastError();

    if (err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        fd_set wfd;
        FD_ZERO(&wfd);
        FD_SET(sock, &wfd);

        fd_set efd;
        FD_ZERO(&efd);
        FD_SET(sock, &efd);

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = ...;
        timeout.tv_usec = ...;

        ret = select(0, NULL, &wfd, &wfd, &timeout);

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            printf("*J* Connect Timeout\n"); 
            // handle timeout as needed ...
            return;
        }

        if ((ret > 0) && FD_ISSET(sock, &efd))
        {
            err = 0;
            getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&err, sizeof(err));
            ret = -1;
        }
    }

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("*J* Connect Failed: %d\n", err); 
        // handle fatal error as needed ...
        return;
    }
}

...

char message[80];
sprintf(message, "CONNECT 192.168.1.68:3001 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
printf("*J* Message loaded.\n"); //*J*
printf("*J* %s\n", message); //*J*

char *pmsg = message;
int len = strlen(message);

do
{
    ret = send(sock, pmsg, len, 0);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        err = getLastSocketError();    

        if (err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            fd_set wfd;
            FD_ZERO(&wfd);
            FD_SET(sock, &wfd);

            timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec = ...;
            timeout.tv_usec = ...;

            ret = select(0, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &timeout);

            if (ret > 0)
                continue;

            if (ret == 0)
            {
                printf("*J* Send Timeout\n"); 
                // handle timeout as needed ...
                return;
            }

            err = WSAGetLastError();
        }

        printf("*J* Send Failed: %d\n", err); 
        // handle fatal error as needed ...
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        pmsg += ret;
        len += ret;
    }
}
while (len > 0);

printf("*J* Data Sent\n");

...

printf("*J* Close Socket\n");
closesocket(sock);
```

If you want something a little more cross-platform, try this instead (or use a cross-platform socket library instead):

```
int getLastSocketError()
{
    #ifdef WINDOWS
    return WSAGetLastError();
    #else
    return errno;
    #endif
};

int ret, err;
...
ret = connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize);
if (ret == -1)
{
    err = getLastSocketError();    

    if (
        #ifdef WINDOWS
        err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK
        #else
        err == EINPROGRESS
        #endif
        )
    {
        #ifndef WINDOWS
        do {
        #endif

        fd_set wfd;
        FD_ZERO(&wfd);
        FD_SET(sock, &wfd);

        #ifdef WINDOWS
        fd_set efd;
        FD_ZERO(&efd);
        FD_SET(sock, &efd);
        #endif

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = ...;
        timeout.tv_usec = ...;

        #ifdef WINDOWS
        ret = select(0, NULL, &wfd, &wfd, &timeout);
        #else
        ret = select(sock+1, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &timeout);
        #endif

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            printf("*J* Connect Timeout\n"); 
            // handle timeout as needed ...
            return;
        }

        #ifdef WINDOWS
        if ((ret > 0) && FD_ISSET(sock, &efd))
        {
            err = 0;
            getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&err, sizeof(err));
            ret = -1;
        }
        #endif

        #ifndef WINDOWS
        } while ((ret == -1) && (errno == EINTR));
        #endif
    }

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("*J* Connect Failed: %d\n", err); 
        // handle fatal error as needed ...
        return;
    }
}

...

char message[80];
sprintf(message, "CONNECT 192.168.1.68:3001 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
printf("*J* Message loaded.\n"); //*J*
printf("*J* %s\n", message); //*J*

char *pmsg = message;
int len = strlen(message);

do
{
    ret = send(sock, pmsg, len, 0);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        err = getLastSocketError();    

        if (
            #ifdef WINDOWS
            err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK
            #else
            (err == EWOULDBLOCK) || (err == EAGAIN)
            #endif
            )
        {
            fd_set wfd;
            FD_ZERO(&wfd);
            FD_SET(sock, &wfd);

            timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec = ...;
            timeout.tv_usec = ...;

            ret = select(
                #ifdef WINDOWS
                0
                #else
                sock+1
                #endif
                , NULL, &wfd, NULL, &timeout);

            if (ret > 0)
                continue;

            if (ret == 0)
            {
                printf("*J* Send Timeout\n"); 
                // handle timeout as needed ...
                return;
            }

            err = getLastSocketError();
        }

        #ifndef WINDOWS
        if (err != EINTR)
        #endif
        {
            printf("*J* Send Failed: %d\n", err); 
            // handle fatal error as needed ...
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pmsg += ret;
        len += ret;
    }
}
while (len > 0);

printf("*J* Data Sent\n");

...

printf("*J* Close Socket\n");

#ifdef WINDOWS
closesocket(sock);
#else
close(sock);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize)) {
    ...
    if (send(sock, message, strlen(message) + 1, 0) < 0) printf("*J* Send Failed: %d\n", errno);
```

The block within `if (connect(..` is entered when `connect` returns a non-zero value. Since connect returns 0 on success and -1 on error (permanent or temporarily) this means that the block is entered when `connect` is not (yet) successful. Calling `send` in this case will in most cases fail since the connection is not yet done but in some lucky cases might succeed if the connection was successful in the meantime.

The intend was probably to enter the block if the connect succeded. In this case the correct handling would have been

```
if (0 == connect(sock, pSockAddr, iSockAddrSize)) {
     ...
```

Of course, since non-blocking sockets are used it is unlikely that the connect will succeed immediately so there would be a proper handling of non-blocking connect required.

Comment: Also, with a non-blocking socket, `connect()` may not be able to succeed immediately, so you have to check the return value for 0 on success and -1 on error.  If the error is `EINPROGRESS`, you have to use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to wait for the connection to actually complete before you can then exchange data.

Comment: Also, using `strlen+1` on the `send()` is wrong as well, as it sends the null terminator, which is not part of the `CONNECT` protocol. The null terminator will be treated as application data that gets forwarded as-is through the tunnel to the next server (if the tunnel is successful), breaking communications with that server.  Also, `send()` is not guaranteed to send everything it is given (especialy with a non-blocking socket), so you have to pay attention to the return value and keep calling `send()` in a loop to resent any unsent bytes until all bytes have been sent, or a real error occurs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The (...) contained checks for `EINPROGRESS`, but I wasn't using select! It is working now that I added a select to wait for the socket to be ready. You got the right answer if you want to post it!

Comment: Good advice Steffen. I actually did have checks for non-immediate connections, but I didn't wait for them to resolve, so my code was only working when they connected really fast.